Secret Service outside X?
I am trying to use the Secret Service (not NSA/CIA, but the Linux one, through secret-tool command) outside of X.
I managed to use it with kwalletd and with keepassxc. But kwalletd needs KDE and hence graphic environment, and keepassxc is a pain because it asks for authorizations every-single-time it is used.
Is there a way to use the Secret Service outside X?

https://manpages.org/secret-tool
